# automatic scan scheduled with clamtk for ubuntu 12.04 does not work

Tags: 12.04, scanning, clamav, schedule

the automatic scanner that i have scheduled with clamtk for ubuntu 12.04 does not work. i have to do the job manually.
is there a code i can punch into the console that will fix this problem so that an automatic scan can be scheduled on clamTK ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule the scanning task with the application **Scheduled Task** which is the task scheduler in Ubuntu.

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

In menu, go to `New` > `Reccurrent task`

[image]

The command for run ClamAV scanning is :

```
clamscam [OPTIONS] [DIRECTORY TO SCAN]
```

Options :

**-r** : To recursively scan all the files 
**-i** : List the infected files
**--bell** : Ring a tone at when virus is found

So the command to scan all the directories is :

```
sudo clamscan -r -i --bell /
```

You can add this command and schedule the time in the following window

[image]